# Redirecting to MVC page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I would like to redirect to another page using jQuery code.  This is my event declaration:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        var menu = $("#menu").kendoMenu({
            dataSource: [
                { text: "EMSS", cssClass: "emss" }
            ]
        }).css({ width: "100%" }).data("kendoMenu");

        //event declaration
        $("li.emss").click(redirectToPage);
    });

    function redirectToPage(url) {
        window.location.ref = url;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="menu" style="margin-right:0px;"></div>
```

How do I pass the page I would like to redirect to to the function?  Or how can I do this in any other way?

Btw, I'm trying to redirect to an MVC page.

Comment: You have a typo: `window.location.ref` should be `window.location.href`

Comment: Thank you, @Thijs.  Not really the solution to my problem, but it was something that was wrong.  I've fixed it and, along with another answer, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the argument to the function in the click handler

```
$("li.emss").click(function(){
  redirectToPage('my url');
});
```